# Using django-cassandra-engine sessions and getting a error

Tags: python, django, cassandra

I'm using django-cassandra-engine for storage the sessions, when run the server I get this error:

```
RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.sessions.models.Session doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS
```

The steps I followed are these [link](http://r4fek.github.io/django-cassandra-engine/guide/sessions/)

```
INSTALLED_APPS += ['django_cassandra_engine.sessions']
SESSION_BACKEND = 'django_cassandra_engine.sessions.backends.db'
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the Outdated docs [`SESSION_ENGINE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#session-engine)

```
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django_cassandra_engine.sessions.backends.db'
```

change `SESSION_BACKEND` for `SESSION_ENGINE`